# How to add advanced Kafka configurations to the Landoop `fast-data-dev` image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Does anyone know how to pass custom Kafka configuration options to the `landoop/fast-data-dev` docker image?

Since there is no way to puss a custom config file and/or config params, what I've tried so far was to mount my own `server.properties` config file into `/opt/confluent/etc/kafka` by adding the following into my docker compose file

```
landoop:
hostname: 'landoop'
image: 'landoop/fast-data-dev:latest'
expose:
  - '3030'
ports:
  - '3030:3030'
environment:
  - RUNTESTS=0
  - RUN_AS_ROOT=1
volumes:
  - ./docker/landoop/tmp:/tmp
  - ./docker/landoop/opt/confluent/etc/kafka:/opt/confluent/etc/kafka
```

however, this causes Kafka to throw the following logs:

```
landoop_1       | 2017-09-28 11:53:03,886 INFO exited: broker (exit status 1; not expected)
landoop_1       | 2017-09-28 11:53:04,749 INFO spawned: 'broker' with pid 281
landoop_1       | 2017-09-28 11:53:05,851 INFO success: broker entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
landoop_1       | 2017-09-28 11:53:11,867 INFO exited: rest-proxy (exit status 1; not expected)
landoop_1       | 2017-09-28 11:53:12,604 INFO spawned: 'rest-proxy' with pid 314
landoop_1       | 2017-09-28 11:53:13,024 INFO exited: schema-registry (exit status 1; not expected)
landoop_1       | 2017-09-28 11:53:13,735 INFO spawned: 'schema-registry' with pid 341
landoop_1       | 2017-09-28 11:53:13,739 INFO success: rest-proxy entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

in addition, when I go to http://localhost:3030/kafka-topics-ui/, I see the following:

```
KAFKA REST
/api/kafka-rest-proxy 
CONNECTIVITY ERROR
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that i did which simplified the whole process. This is valid only for dev environment

1. Start the docker with a interactive shell as the entry point
2. Start the docker on the host network
3. Make necessary changes to the server.properties file include the host IP where the docker was running (as mentioned in (2) docker is running on host network)

** 4. If you want to make any advanced configuration, you may do now**

5. Run the actual entry point "/usr/local/bin/setup-and-run.sh"

Actual commands used:

1. Start the container

sudo docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash --net=host --rm  -e ADV_HOST=HOSTIP        landoop/fast-data-dev:latest

2. Add following to /run/broker/server.properties

advertised.host.name = HOST-IP

advertised.port = 9092

3. Run /usr/local/bin/setup-and-run.sh

Answer (score 0):

---

At today, with latest version of landoop/fast-data-dev is possible to specify custom Kafka configuration options by converting the configuration option to uppercase, replacing dots with underscores and prepending with KAFKA_.
For example if you want to set specific values for "log.retention.bytes" and "log.retention.hours" you should add the following to your docker compose environment section:

```
environment:
  KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_BYTES: 1073741824
  KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS: 48
  ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1                  
  RUNTESTS: 0   
  BROWSECONFIGS: 1
```

You can specify this way also configuration options for other services (  schema registry, connect, rest proxy ). Check doc for details https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/fast-data-dev/.

Once the container is up you can confirm this by looking at configuration file at the following path inside the container:

`/run/broker/server.properties`

or also through the Landoop UI at the following URL if you've set "BROWSECONFIGS" to 1 on the environments parameters:

http://127.0.0.1:3030/config/broker/server.properties